# Active bounty advertisement bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The active bounty community advertisement seems to be broken, displaying 2 bounty for a total of 550 rep, when the [featured page](https://security.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) shows 4 for a total of 700 rep

[image]

Comment: It looks like the information is just stale.  I'm not sure where the code for that ad lives or how often it's refreshed, but two of those questions have had bounties for 4 days and are worth 550, the other two, worth 150, were added today.  The ad was probably made before the last two bounties were added.

Comment: @BrianNickel It seems to be that indeed, as i couldn't get it natturaly, i've checked the one in the [meta post for community ads](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2634/145695) and it's updated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is outside the scope of our site.  This image is not owned by us but a third party (I think https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad).

As far as why the information is wrong, I would blame caching.  There was a point when this information was true.  There were two bounties worth 550.  Then two more bounties were added bringing it to 700.  The stale information just needed to age out of whatever cache it was in.